# Passing client-side certs through two NGINX servers and delivering them to a back-end application

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Is it possible to configure NGINX to pass client-side certificates through two NGINX servers and send the original client-side certificate to destination app?

I've included a diagram below:
[image: curl to NGINX-A to K8S NGINX-B to App]

Highlights are:

1. curl (or a browser) is configured with client side certs.
2. Mutual authentication is required on both NGINX services.
3. Trusted certs and requisite CA certs are configured.
4. NGINX takes client side cert and passes it as HTTP header fields.
5. The 2nd NGINX server is actually in a K8S cluster.

I've setup this example but haven't (yet) gotten it to work.  The App says that the `ssl-client-cert` is not present.

If I go directly from `curl` to `NGINX-B` then it does work, and the App gets the client-side cert information in the `ssl-client-cert`, `ssl-client-subject-dn`, and `ssl-client-issuer-dn` fields.

### Looking for solution

I've found a fair bit of good documentation on NGINX but what I've tried (so far) has not worked.  I've tried implementing the solution
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-tcp-traffic-upstream/.  This webpage does a good job walking through the configuration changes.

I'm a first time user of NGINX and it is possible that I've just picked the wrong example to use to implement this solution.

My work around is to implement a Java application to do the work of NGINX-A.

#### NGINX Configuration for NGINX-A

A snippet of the NGINX-A `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file is shown below.
I've highlighted only the configuration items that are important for SSL, mutual authentication and forwarding CERT information in headers as shown in the diagram.

```
FILE: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (on NGINX-A)
http {
    upstream k8s {
        server nginx-b.k8s.example.com;
    }
    server {
        listen                 443 ssl;
        ssl_verify_client      on;
        ssl_certificate        /etc/nginx/certs/identity.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/certs/identity.key;
        ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/ca-bundle.crt;

        location /upstream {
            proxy_pass 'https://nginx-b.k8s.example.com';
            proxy_set_header ssl-client-cert $ssl_client_escaped_cert;
            proxy_set_header ssl-client-subject-dn $ssl_client_s_dn;
            proxy_set_header ssl-client-issuer-dn $ssl_client_i_dn;
            
            proxy_ssl_certificate          /etc/nginx/certs/identity.pem;
            proxy_ssl_certificate_key      /etc/nginx/certs/identity.key;
            proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate  /etc/nginx/certs/ca-bundle.crt;
            proxy_ssl_verify               on;
            proxy_ssl_verify_depth         4;
        }
```

#### NGINX Configuration for NGINX-B

In my case, NGINX-B is actually in a Kubernetes (K8S) cluster and I don't have admin rights for that K8S cluster so I can only go by what the admins have told me and what I've observed, but it appears be configured properly for passing client certs to the app.

The ingress object for the application has the following configuration for it.

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
    # Enable client certificate authentication
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "on"
    # Create the secret containing the trusted ca certificates
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: "my-ns/ca-bundle"
    # Specify the verification depth in the client certificates chain
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-depth: "4"
    # Specify if certificates are passed to upstream server
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream: "true"
  tls:
    - secretName: cert-to-use
      hosts:
        - mydns.in.k8s.example.com
```

### Other findings

Setting up a Java TLS app with SSL debugging enabled, I was able to prove that `NGINX-A` is both sending it's NGINX-A cert when making the TLS connection to `App2` and also placing `client1` **cert info** into the HTTP headers (as it's configured to do, see NGINX-A `nginx.conf` configuration above).

[image]

## Summary

In summary, is it possible to configure NGINX to support the type of connection I'm requesting?  If so, what is the configuration for the two servers?  How does NGINX handle the case when it receives the SSL Header fields (`ssl-client-cert`, `ssl-client-subject-dn` and `ssl-client-issuer-dn`)?